# Android _ How to get the position of marker on google map v2 and match it to the array of Latlng

Tags: java, android, api, google-maps, marker

Hello everyone I am new dealing with google map API , and I have a list of LatLng object that added  marker on map .

```
 for (LatLng location : camerasLocations) {
                                googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                        .position(location).icon(icon)
                                        .title(cameraList.get(j).getName()));


                            }
```

I want to know the position of the marker on that array when I click on the marker with :

```
  googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
                                            showDialog(getActivity(), "");
                                            return false;
                                        }
                                    });
```

any help please ...

Comment: I don't know if I've understood correctly, if not please provide some further explanation of your question. 
What I got is that - You have some list with LatLng objects, and you are creating your markers basing on them. When the user clicks certain marker you want to know the position of the marker in creation order? Like if the user clicks the marker which has been created at first you want to get 0, 2nd ->1 3rd -> 2 etc ?

Comment: yes that what I want Like when you click on item in listView it return the position of the the item on the list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to set position as tag on marker while adding marker in google map

```
for(int i = 0, i < camerasLocations.size(), i++){

                                Marker marker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                .position(location).icon(icon)
                                .title(cameraList.get(j).getName()))
                                .setTag(i);
                            }

And then you can obtain this marker position in the onclick method using getTag() method : 




googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {

                    Toast.makeText(this, "Marker position >> " + marker.getTag(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return false;
                }
            });
```

Comment: i wrote this question two years ago and now i am facing the same problem , when i google it my question appeared , and i tried your solution and it was simple and perfect very thank you

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, they are not positioned in that way. You would have to handle it yourself. If you are sure you just want to get the index based on the order of creation, you can do sth like that:

Create private field with Map, for storing that information

```
//class field  
private Map<Marker, Integer> markersOrderNumbers = new HashMap<>();
```

Afterward, populate it

```
//Your method
int markerIndex = 0; 
for (LatLng location : camerasLocations) {
                            Marker marker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                    .position(location).icon(icon)
                                    .title(cameraList.get(j).getName()));
                            markersOrderNumbers.put(marker,markerIndex);
                            markerIndex++;
                        }
```

And then you can obtain this index number in the onclick method

```
 googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
                                        Integer index = markersOrderNumbers.get(marker);
                                        //Do whatever you want to
                                        showDialog(getActivity(), "");
                                        return false;
                                    }
                                });
```

I might add that if you are not certainly focused on the index itself but rather on some information that you get using that Id, you can use provided method to map marker with needed information at the first place like:

```
Map<Marker, Whatever> ...
```

Comment: index variable return 0 when I click in every marker

Comment: No sorry it was my It was my fault it return the right index , but i want to assign the Integer on the map to the original array that I take the latLng object from it , (it is array from JSON contains other attribute then lat long value like id , name , time ) how can assign the index to that array to take the name and the id ??

Comment: Integer on the map? I don't get it. And looking at your loop "for (LatLng location : camerasLocations)" your array contains only LatLng. Or maybe you are talking about this "cameraList"? Please provide more information like what is "j". As I've written in my answer you can map markers with your objects from the list, that would be cleaner, better solution in my taste. Like Map<Marker, YourObject> and when the user clicks on a marker you can obtain related object and get it's name time etc.

Comment: yes I am talking about cameralist it is an array hold camera object that i retrieve from web-service , it has more then latitude and longitude attribute that I create camera location marker from it Like : name , id , speed , time . I want to get the name and the id when I click on the marker that you tech me how to get it position , I tried what you said   Map<Marker, MyObject>  but it keep give me 0 value

Comment: I solved by assign the index of the map to get the value from the list like :      cameraList.get(index).getID() ;............                                                                                      cameraList.get(index).getName(); ........... and thank you for your help :)